# New User OpenID identities in Drupal 7

Tags: users, authentication-authorization

Scenario:

Drupal 7 site recently migrated from Drupal 6. Using OpenID connect module. All users login with Google, using a Google account with a company domain name. (user@company.com). All users that were migrated can still log in. When a new user is created, he or she cannot log in, and the OpenID Identities tab for the new user is blank. The new user is directed back to the login page. The site is also using the [Require Login module](https://www.drupal.org/project/require_login), which states that it works with OpenID.

1. How can I get Drupal to save the OpenID Identity to the user's account? So far my only idea is to give the user a one-time link so he can log in, then ask him to add the https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id code into the "add identities" field.
2. Would that even work, since it's not actually google.com for the others? All the working users have IDs that state the company name (www.company.com/id=longstring).
3. How can I check to see if the site is using the new OpenID protocol and won't stop working on April 20th?

I am having trouble understanding how OpenId works with Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with a similar issue, here is how I solved it.

The problem: using openid signin with a site that shows a splash login page for all anonymous users. You cannot use any splash page configuration that uses redirects, because it interferes with the openid redirect.

Solution: I removed the require login module and enabled the front page module. Then I configured the front page to use an alias with the login page for unauthenticated users, NOT the redirect option. When new users sign in, it automatically uses the company domain to create an openid and then stores it in Drupal.

Sidenote: New users cannot already have an existing account in the Drupal site, even if there is no openid yet assigned. The account is created the first time they sign in . They will not be able to do so if there is already an account attached to their email.